# problems relative to a bad java web application project structure

Tags: java, jsp

I have a directory structure for a web java application + standalone application like this:
src/logic/view/desktop
src/logic/view/web
and
src/logic/bean,control etc...

In src/logic/view/web i have my web application with WEB_INF, META_INF, mypage.jsp etc...

mypage.jsp

```
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
 
 <!-- dichiarazione e instanziazione di un BeanAddReport !-->
<jsp:useBean id="addReportBean" scope="request" class="logic.bean.AddReportBean"/>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Add Report</title>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mycss.css">

</head>
<body>
    
    <img class="backImg" alt="" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/img/backgroundImage2.jpg" width="1366">
        
</body>
</html>
```

and the bean class

```
package logic.bean;

import logic.controlgrafico.AddReportGuiControl;

public class AddReportBean {

    private String queueLen;
    private boolean isLast;
    private Object gui;
    private String attractionName;
    
    public void setQueueLen(String s) {
        queueLen = s;
    }
    
    public void setIsLast(boolean b) {
        isLast = b;
    }
    
    public void setGui(Object gui) {
        this.gui = gui;
    }
    
    public void setAttraction(String a) {
        attractionName = a;
    }
    
    public String getAttraction() {
        return attractionName;
    }
    
    public String getQueueLen() {
        return queueLen;
    }
    
    public boolean getIsLast() {
        return isLast;
    }
    
    public Object getGui() {
        return gui;
    }
}
```

Now my problem is:
when I start the tomcat server I receive a

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /addReport.jsp (line: [5], column: [0]) The value for the useBean class attribute [logic.bean.AddReportBean] is invalid.
```

I think the problem is the project structure and I would tell if there are some configurations, for example in web.xml, that can resolve my problem.

I try to run another dummy project with a different directory structure:
DummyProject/src/bean.java
DummyProject/web/index.jsp where the index.jsp use "useBean" in the same way and all works fine.

Suggest me more detail of how the target class works in useBean tag. Ty so much

**Edit:**
The difference between the two projects is in
C:\Users\simon\eclipse-workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps
The project where all works fine had the path WEB-INF/classes/logic/bean/AddReportBean.class

Why the other project doesn't have this path?

Comment: How is your project built? The class files need to end up in `WEB-INF/classes`. So you should see a file named `WEB-INF/classes/logic/bean/AddReportBean.class`

Comment: I don't see this file in this directory, why? Neither in my dummy project there is WEB-INF/classes

Comment: How is your project built?

Comment: What do you mean? I use Eclipse and TomCat v9.0 to run on server